# Make an array name from two variables' value

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I can make a variable's name from two variables' value:

```
$a = 'tea';
$b = 'pot';
$tea_pot = 'Too Hot';
```

Here if I print or echo `${$a.'_'.$b}`, I will get 'Too Hot' as output.

Similarly I need to make an array's name from two variables' value.
I try this the code below. But it's giving me an error: Undefined variable.

I want something like:
`$k = ${'B'.$a}` where `$a=5` and `$B5 = array('c', 'v', 'b');`
and want to `echo($k[2])`;

the codes that i want to solve is here...

```
$B0 = array('apple', 'crow', 'monkey', 'lion', 'deer', 'bear', 'tiger');
$B1 = array('bad', 'meaningless', 'odd', 'no fare', 'poor', 'old', 'dirty', 'damn', 'rush');
function($set, $number){
     while($set >= 2){
          $set -= 2;
     }
     if($set == 0){
          while($number >= 7){
               $numbur -= 7;
          }
     } else {
          while($number >= 9){
               $numbur -= 9;
          }
     }
     $array = ${'B'.$set}; // Error
     return $array[$number];
}
/*Error: it is saying that here the "${'B'.$set}" is a Undefined variable
where it is a name of an array. what can I do to realize
that it is not a variable but an array.*/
```

Comment: I get `NULL` if I try that (with `var_dump()`)...

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? `${$a.'_'.$b} = array();`  ??

Comment: thanks Michael for your editing...

Comment: Did you forget to paste the code that doesn't work?

Comment: I want something like:
$k = ${'B'.$a} where $a=5 and $B5 = array('c', 'v', 'b');

Comment: Sounds like you should go with multidimensional arrays instead. In most cases variable variables are a bad idea.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got the real problem and its solve...
Here the arrays "B0" and "B1" are places outside the function so you have to declare the ${'B'.$set} as a global array by just adding a single line inside the function before you call it. Like this:

```
$B0 = array('apple', 'crow', 'monkey', 'lion', 'deer', 'bear', 'tiger');
$B1 = array('bad', 'meaningless', 'odd', 'no fare', 'poor', 'old', 'dirty', 'damn', 'rush');
function($set, $number){
     while($set >= 2){
          $set -= 2;
     }
     if($set == 0){
          while($number >= 7){
               $numbur -= 7;
          }
     } else {
          while($number >= 9){
               $numbur -= 9;
          }
     }
     global ${'B'.$set};
     $array = ${'B'.$set};
     return $array[$number];
}
```

now it will understand and will get the array properly and will not show any errors.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use:

`${$name}[$key]`

In this case `${$a.'_'.$b}[$key]`

This will assign the variable name to the array's name.

### EDIT

As Juhana mentioned, it's really much safer to use a multidimensional array though.  Rather than use `$B0`, why not use:

```
$B[0] = array('apple', 'crow', 'monkey', 'lion', 'deer', 'bear', 'tiger');
$B[1] = array('bad', 'meaningless', 'odd', 'no fare', 'poor', 'old', 'dirty', 'rush');
```

Then  you can just reference it in your function like so:

```
global $B[$set];

return $B[$set][$number];
```

It's much cleaner.  Just because the variable creation method works, doesn't mean that it is the best or safest method to use.  In your case, it is not as much a safety concern because you are appending the variable name after `B`.  But if you were not doing this, and you were just directly referencing a string to use as a variable name, you could run into problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array['tea']['pot'] = 'Too Hot';
echo $array[$a][$b];
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a **BAD** idea to use this as several other people mentioned. But if you feel strongly about it, it's simple:

```
$B5 = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$a = 5;
$k = 'B'.$a;
```

Using `var_dump($$k);` you'll get

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5) "three" }
```

To access an array value via its index, use either:

```
echo ${$k}[0];
```

or via another variable:

```
$another_var = $$k;
echo $another_var[0];
```

Comment: The downvote is rather dumb - pay attention to the OP question.